# Reading a Tuple Assignment (e.g.written as such d1: p, m, h, = 20, 15, 22) from a Text File and Performing Calculations with Each Variable (e.g. p*h)

Tags: python, tuples, file-handling

I'm a reading a text file with several hundred lines of data in python. The text file contains data written as a tuple assignment. For example, the data looks exactly like this in the text file:

```
d1: p,h,t,m= 74.15 18 6 0.1 ign: 0.0003
 d2: p,h,t,m= 54. 378 -0.14 0.1 ign: 0.0009
```

How can I separate the data as such:

```
p = 20

t = 15
```

etc. 
Then, how can I perform calculations on the tuple assignment? For example calculate:
p*p = 20*15?

I am not sure if I should convert the tuple assignment to an array. But I was not successful. In addition, I do not know how to get rid of the d1 and d2: which is there to identify which data set I am looking at

I have read the data and picked out the lines that have the data, (ignoring the First Set line and of Data Given as line)

The results that I need would be:

p (from first set of data d1)*p(from first set of data d2) = 20*15 = 300

p (from second set of data d1)*p(from second set of data d2) = 12*5 = 60

I believe I would need to do this over some kind of loop so that I can separate the data in all the lines in the file.

I would appreciate any help on this! I couldn't find anything pertaining to my question. I would only find how to deal with tuples in the simplest manner but nothing on how to extract variables and performing calculations on a tuple assignment contained in a text file.

EDIT:

After looking at the answer given for this question given by @JArunMani, I went back to try to see if I can understand each line of code. I understand that we need to create a dictionary that fills in the respective values for p, q, etc...
When I try to rewrite the code to how I understand it, I have:

```
with open("d.txt") as fp: # Opens the file 
  # The database kinda thing here
 line = fp.readline() # Read the file's first line
 number, _,cont = line.partition(":")#separates m1 from p, m, h, n =..."
 print(cont)
 data, _,ignore = cont.partition("int") #separates int from p, m, h, n =..."
 print(data) #prints tuple assignment needed
 keys, _,values = data.partition("=")
 print(keys) #prints p, m, h, n
 print(values) #prints values (all numbers after =)
 thisdict = {} #creating an empty dictionary to fill with keys and values
 thisdict[keys] = values
 print(thisdict)
 if "m" in thisdict:
     print("Yes")
```

print(thisdict) gives me the Output: {' p,m,h,n': ' 76 6818 2.2 1 '}

However, if "m" in thisdict: did not print anything. I do not understand why m is not in the dictionary, yet print(thisdict) shows that thisdict = {} has been filled. Also, is it necessary to add the for loop in the answer given below?

Thank you.

**EDIT 2**

I am now trying my second attempt to this problem. I combining both answers to write the code since I using what I understand from each code:
    def DataExtract(self):
    with open("muonsdata.txt") as fp: # Opens the file

```
   line = fp.readline() # Read the file's first line
   number, _,cont = line.partition(":")#separates m1 from pt, eta, phi, m =..."
   print(cont)
   data, _,ignore = cont.partition("dptinv") #separates dptinv from pt, eta, phi, m =..."
   print(data) #prints tuple assignment needed
   keys, _,values = data.partition("=")
   print(keys) #prints pt, eta, phi, m
   print(values) #prints values (all numbers after =)
   key = [k for k in keys.split(",")]
   value = [v for v in values.strip().split(" ")]
   print(key)
   print(value)
   thisdict = {}
   data = {}
   for k, v in zip(key, value): #creating an empty dictionary to fill with keys and values
         thisdict[k] = v
         print(thisdict)
         if "m" in thisdict:

             print("Yes")


x = DataExtract("C:/Users/username/Desktop/data.txt")
mul_p = x['m1']['p'] * x['d2']['p']
print(mul_p)
```

However, this gives me the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read.py", line 29, in 
    mul_p = x['d1']['p'] * x['d2']['p']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

**EDIT 3**

I have the code made from a combination of answers 1 and 2, BUT...
the only thing is that I have the code written and working but why doesn't the while loop go on until we reach the end of the file. I only get one answer from the calculating the values from the first two lines, but what about the remaining lines? Also, it seems like it is not reading the d2 data lines (or the line = fp.readline is not doing anything), because when I try to calculate m , I get the error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read.py", line 37, in 
    m = math.cosh(float(data[" m2"]["eta"])) * float(data["m1"][" pt"])
KeyError: ' m2'

Here is my code that I have:

```
import math
with open("d.txt") as fp: # Opens the file

    data ={} #final dictionary
    line = fp.readline() # Read the file's first line

    while line: #continues to end of file

        name, _,cont = line.partition(":")#separates d1 from p, m, h, t =..."
        #print(cont)
        numbers, _,ignore = cont.partition("ign") #separates ign from p, m, h, t =..."
        #print(numbers) #prints tuple assignment needed
        keys, _,values = numbers.partition("=")
        #print(keys) #prints p, m, h, t
        #print(values) #prints values (all numbers after =)
        key = [k for k in keys.split(",")]
        value = [v for v in values.strip().split(" ")]
        #print(key) #prints pt, eta, phi, m
        #print(value)
        thisdict = {}
        for k, v in zip(key, value): #creating an empty dictionary to fill with keys and values
            #thisdict[k] = v
            #print(thisdict)
        #data[name]=thisdict        
            line = fp.readline()#read next lines, not working I think
            thisdict[k] = v
            data[name]=thisdict
            print(thisdict)

        #if " m2" in thisdict:
           #print("Yes")

       #print(data)       

#mul_p = float(data["d1"][" p"])*float(data["d1"]["m"])
    m = math.cosh(float(data[" d2"]["m"])) * float(data["m1"][" p"])
#m1 = float(data["d1"][" p"]) * float(2)
    print(m)

#print(mul_p)
```

If I replace the d2's with d1 the code runs fine, except it skips the last d1. I do not know what I am doing wrong. Would appreciate any input or guidance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question is not quite clear. Just what do you mean by "separate the data"--what should be the result? For example, for the line `d1: p, t, m= 20, 15, 25` do you want to get the strings `"p = 20"` etc., or do you want a variable named `p` to get the value `20`, or do you want something else? And what do you mean by "perform calculations on the tuple assignment"? How is your program to know that you want to calculate `p * p`? Is `d1:`before every line or only the first line? And so on. Please clarify.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your reply. I apologize for not getting my  question across clearly. But what I am trying to do is:

Comment: A *full* example would help, where you show a complete (short) file and show just what the result of that file should be.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your reply. I apologize for not getting my question across clearly. d1: is before every line that contains the data I need. I have two sets of data d1: p, t, m = 20, 15, 25 and d2: = p, t, m = 15, 19, 22. I need to get the p from the set in d1: and multiply it with the p in data set d2. In which case,  I need a variable named p from data set d1 to get the value 20 and multiply it with the other variable named p in data set d2 to get the value 15. I am not sure how that would be programmed.

Comment: What do you mean by "every line that contains the data I need"? Are there multiple lines in the same file that start with `d1:`? Do they all contain `p` or just one? What if none of them contain `p`? If there are multiple `p`s in those lines, which `p` is the program to use? (Regarding your last edit) How are the "sets of data" distinguished in the file? You really need to show one full example and state the exact results you want from that example.

Comment: I have edited my question showing an example of the file that I have and showing what the results would need to look like. Please let me know if you need further clarification to the problem.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple lines in the same file that start with d1: and they all contain p.

Comment: The data is accumulated through a simulation; that is, the values of p, t, etc are obtained repeatedly through a simulation.Events are simulated and give out values for p, t, etc for each event done. I can give a short snippet of the text file but it is basically how I wrote it in the question.

Answer (score 3):

So the following function returns a dictionary with values of 'p', 'q' and other variables. But I leave it to you to find out how to multiply or perform operations on them ^^

```
def DataExtract(path): # 'path' is the path to the data file 
    fp = open(path) # Opens the file 
    data = {} # The database kinda thing here
    line = fp.readline() # Read the file's first line
    while line: # This goes on till we reach end of file (EOF)
        name, _, cont = line.partition(":") # So this gives, 'd1', ':', 'p, q, ...'
        keys, _, values = cont.partition("=") # Now we split the text into RHS and LHS
        keys = keys.split(",") # Split the variables by ',' as separator
        values = values.split(",") # Split the values
        temp_d = {} # Dict for variables
        for i in range(len(keys)):
            key = keys[i].strip() # Get the item at the index and remove left-right spaces
            val = values[i].strip() # Same
            temp_d[key] = float(val) # Store it in dictionary but as number
        data[name.strip()] = temp_d # Store the temp_d itself in main dict
        line = fp.readline() # Now read next line
    fp.close() # Close the file
    return data # Return the data
```

I used simple methods, to make it easy for you. Now to access data, you have to do something like this:

```
x = DataExtract("your_file_path")
mul_p = x['d1']['p'] * x['d2']['p']
print(mul_p) # Tadaaa !
```

Feel free to comment...

Comment: Thank you very much! This is great. I am just trying to understand each line of code well. Do you mind explaining what the purpose or function of name, _,cont is in the code? I understand that line.partition gives 'd1', ':', 'p, t,..' Thanks!

Comment: I am getting a syntax error from the first line of code you put out: def DataExtract('C:/Users/username/Desktop/data.txt'): I get Syntax Error invalid syntax and an ^ pointing at the end of .txt') Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Partition gives three strings. String before sep, sep, string after sep. We need only the string before and after. So I just gave a random variable `_` you can give any other name also.

Comment: You should enter the value of path while calling the function. Not while defining it. So just copy the function and run it. Call it by using `DB = DataExtract("C:/Users/username/Desktop/Data.txt")`

Comment: Accept the answer, if it worked, otherwise let me know why it didn't.

Comment: Ok, I will try out your suggestion and I will definitely accept the answer once it worked.

Comment: The code didn't really work but I will try to see if I can work on it first

Comment: I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trial.py", line 20, in <module>
    x = DataExtract()
  File "trial.py", line 14, in DataExtract
    temp_d[key] = float(val) # Store it in dictionary but as number
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: I have also edited my question above. Is it necessary to have the for loop that you included? Also if I get rid of the float(val) and just write (val), I get the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trial.py", line 20, in <module>
    x = DataExtract()
  File "trial.py", line 13, in DataExtract
    val = values[i].strip() # Same
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I have the code written and working but why doesn't the while loop go on until we reach the end of the file. I only get one answer from the first two lines, but what about the remaining lines?

Comment: oh stupid me ! sorry. i shall recheck it n tell you

Comment: I think I fixed everything except that it won't read the last two lines. But I got rid of the errors and was able to let the code recognize all the keys.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is quite familiar with @JArunMani, but it's shorter a bit and sure that can run successfully.

The idea is return your data to dictionary.

```py
lines = "d1: p,h,t,m= 74.15 18 6 0.1 ign: 0.0003\nd2: p,h,t,m= 54. 378 -0.14 0.1 ign: 0.0009".split("\n")  # lines=open("d.txt",'r').read().split("\n")
data = {}
for line in lines:
    l = line.split("ign")[0]   # remove "ign:.."
    name_dict, vals_dict = l.split(":")         #['d1',' p,h,t,m= 74.15 18 6 0.1']
    keys_str, values_str = vals_dict.split("=") #[' p,h,t,m',' 74.15 18 6 0.1']
    keys=[k for k in keys_str.strip().split(',')]       #['p','h','t','m']
    values=[float(v) for v in values_str.strip().split(' ')] #[74.15, 18, 6, 0.1]
    sub_dict = {}
    for k,v in zip(keys, values):
        sub_dict[k]=v
    data[name_dict]=sub_dict
```

Result:

```py
>>>data
{'d1': {'p': 74.15, 'h': 18.0, 't': 6.0, 'm': 0.1}, 'd2': {'p': 54.0, 'h': 378.0, 't': -0.14, 'm': 0.1}}
>>>data['d1']['p']*data['d2']['p']
4004.1000000000004
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198617/discussion-on-answer-by-le-t-thanh-reading-a-tuple-assignment-e-g-written-as-s).