# Syntax Error invalid syntax for def Data(path)

Tags: python, function

Here is the line of code where I am getting an error

```
def Data('C:/Users/username/Desktop/d.txt'):
    fp = open('C:/Users/username/Desktop/d.txt')
```

I get the following error:

```
File "read.py", line 17
    def DataExtract('C:/Users/username/Desktop/d.txt'):
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Not sure what the problem is and what is causing the invalid syntax

Thank you!

Here is the code I am working on:

```
def DataExtract('C:/Users/username/Desktop/d.txt'):
fp = open('C:/Users/username/Desktop/d.txt')
data = {}
line = fp.read().split("\n")[2:7:5]:
while line:
    name, _, cont = line.partition(":")
    keys, _, values = cont.partition("=")
    keys = keys.split(",")
    values = values.split(",")
    temp_d = {}
    for i in range(len(keys)):
        key = key[i].strip()
        val = values[i].strip()
        temp_d[key] = float(val)
    data[name] = temp_d
    line = fp.readline()
fp.close()
```

return data

```
x = DataExtract('C:/Users/username/Desktop/d.txt')
mul_p = x['d1']['p'] * x['d2']['p']
print(mul_p)
```

Comment: Your function definitions and calls are not matching up?

Comment: Do you mind explaining what you mean a little further?

Comment: Couple of issues,  your indentation under the def is not correct.  all lines should move right about 3 spaces, 2nd your def line should not have the 'path' in it.  it should have nothing or the variables that the passed in parameters are set to.

Comment: This is weird. You asked a question and I gave you this function as answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57640068/reading-a-tuple-assignment-e-g-written-as-such-d1-p-m-h-20-15-22-from/57640467#57640467 You told me its not working and I told you why. And now you are asking it as a new question itself -_-

Comment: Yes, I tried your code; but it didn't work and I think it was because I was not understanding some parts of it and not using the code right. I am new to python and not sure how things work just yet. I am just trying to learn some of the details where I get errors on. But I am still working on the code you gave me...thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned earlier in the comments by @LhasaDad.

I am observing two errors in your attached code.

**First Error:**

First is the "def" statement. The function needs a variable placeholder not the value of the variable. For example:

```py
>>> def fun('hello'):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def fun('hello'):
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> def fun(5):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def fun(5):
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The correct way is

```py
>>> def fun(var):
...     print(var)
...
>>> #Then call the function using below method
...
>>> fun('hello')
hello
>>> fun(5)
5
```

**Second Error:**

There should always be and indentation (tab or 4 spaces gap after a def statement)

So in your case hopefully this will work

```py
def DataExtract(file_path):
    fp = open(file_path)
    data = {}
    line = fp.read().split("\n")[2:7:5]
    while line:
        name, _, cont = line.partition(":")
        keys, _, values = cont.partition("=")
        keys = keys.split(",")
        values = values.split(",")
        temp_d = {}
        for i in range(len(keys)):
            key = keys[i].strip()
            val = values[i].strip()
            temp_d[key] = float(val)
        data[name] = temp_d
        line = fp.readline()
    fp.close()


# Now call the function as
DataExtract('C:/Users/username/Desktop/d.txt')
```

You can also read how to use python functions from def 
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp